# JQuery: Start object as hidden in a way that allows .fadeIn() to work

Tags: jquery, hide, fadein

I have an object that I want to start as hidden. I have tried to use each one of these styles one at a time. I have them in a class, not as inline styles.

```
display:none;
```

and

```
opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);
```

Now, these both worked obviously, the objects load hidden. The issue is that when I use these, the JQuery .fadeIn() function doesn't work. In fact, when I set the opacity to .5 (50), the fade in only fades in to .5 (50).

So what can I default the object to that will allow the .fadeIn() function to work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you only use `display:none` the `fadeIn()` should work. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7FzR/1/

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to `fadeIn` a child of the element you attach those styles to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code with working version

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery​

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('p').fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

CSS

```
p {
    display:none;
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
​
```

Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/2p2v4/

Comment: Depending on your layout, you may not want to start with `display:none;`, and luckily this seems to work without it.

Answer (score 2):

you may use below written or just add your code at the bottom of page

```
.fadeInOnLoad
{
  display:none;
}

      <div class="fadeInOnLoad">iam visible after page is loaded</div>

      jQuery(function(){
           // your fade in code, call it after dom is ready
            jQuery('.fadeInOnLoad').fadeIn();
        });
```

i think your problem is

- you are calling fade in before the
  dom elements are created in browser
- or using jQuery , visual studio  version, as i remember there was some
  bug in jQuery's opacity  thing in   visual studio version